# plupload variable upload path?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using plupload to upload files to my server (http://www.plupload.com/index.php), however I wanted to know if there was any way of making the upload path variable.

Basically I need to select the upload path folder first, then choose the files using plupload and then upload to the initially selected folder.

I've tried a few different ways but I can't seem to pass along the variable folder path to the upload.php file. I'm using the flash version of plupload.

If someone could help me out, that would be fantastic!! :)

Here's my plupload jquery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes: 'flash',
    url: '/assets/upload/upload.php',
    max_file_size: '10mb',
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    unique_names: false,
    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    resize: {width: 500, height: 350, quality: 100},
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url: '/assets/upload/flash/plupload.flash.swf'    
  });
});
```

And here's the upload.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

    // HTTP headers for no cache etc
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    // Settings
 $targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/uploads"; //temp directory <- need these to be variable
 $finalDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/uploads2"; //final directory <- need these to be variable
    $cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 60 * 60; // Temp file age in seconds

    // 5 minutes execution time
    @set_time_limit(5 * 60);
    // usleep(5000);

    // Get parameters
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunk"] : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunks"] : 0;
    $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

    // Clean the fileName for security reasons
    $fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $fileName);

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir))
        @mkdir($targetDir);

    // Remove old temp files
    if (is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            $filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

            // Remove temp files if they are older than the max age
            if (preg_match('/\\.tmp$/', $file) && (filemtime($filePath) < time() - $maxFileAge))
                @unlink($filePath);
        }

        closedir($dir);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');

    // Look for the content type header
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
        $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

    if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
        $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

    if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            // Open temp file
            $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
            if ($out) {
                // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
                $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

                if ($in) {
                    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                        fwrite($out, $buff);
                } else
                    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

                fclose($out);
                unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)){
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
                }

            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');


            fclose($out);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    //Moves the file from $targetDir to $finalDir after receiving the final chunk
    if($chunk == ($chunks-1)){
        rename($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $finalDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);
    }

    // Return JSON-RPC response
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have uploaded them to the initial upload directory, let your script [move](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) them to the correct position.

Comment: I have the upload.php script moving them into uploads (temporary) and then into uploads2 (final) currently, but users need to select the folder destination they want to upload into, before uploading the files. I don't know how to pass a "folder" variable/select option from the plupload script into the upload.php file.

Comment: Simply make a <select> input element with possible folder locations, and in your script get the folder name from $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the same problem for me:

```
        url: 'plupload.php?<?php echo 'plupload_form_id='.$form_id.'&plupload_data_id='.$form_danni_instance_id; ?>'
```

and in the plupload.php:

```
// relative path from current directory to the final one (for the record in the form)
$uploaddir = 'images/uploads/form_id_'.$form_id.'/'.$form_danni_instance_id; 
// relative path from current directory for the form
$uploaddir2 = 'images/uploads/form_id_'.$form_id; 

if (!is_dir($uploaddir2))
{
    // first create the folder for the form, if doesn't exist
    mkdir($uploaddir2);
}

if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
{
    // Then create the folder for the record, where images are going to be uploaded
    mkdir($uploaddir)
}

$targetDir = $uploaddir;
```

I cut some code just to be simple example, but still working one.

I'm using dynamically created tables in in the database from the user itself.

So I needed the following path:

Base dir for all uploaded images:

images/uploads/

for table with id=118 for example i'm creating:

images/uploads/form_id_118/

and then the final folder(s) in which are uploaded files look like:

images/uploads/form_id_118/1/

or

images/uploads/form_id_118/15/

or

images/uploads/form_id_118/2129/

Here 1 or 15 or 2129 is the ID of a record in that table.

(Just for clarifying: in my CMS database table equals to HTML form, as creating a form, the user actually creates table for it in the database.)

Answer (score 1):

Add multipart_params to general settings of the `$("div#uploader").pluploadQueue`

```
multipart_params : {
    "targetDir" : "someDir",
    "paramName1" : "value1 for own use",
    "paramName2" : "value2 for own use"
}
```

Then use it on the server side script (settings.url) with `$_REQUEST['targetDir']`